# How to replace the error message in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a form validation using `jquery.validate.min.js`.

Error message will display on empty fields while clicking submit button.

**And my problem is. I don't want that error message. Have to show red border of every empty field. Can't get idea about that.**

thanks in advance

```js
jQuery(".contact_form").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
            },
            lname: {
                required: true,
            },
            location: {
                required: true,
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            },
            mail: {
                required: true,
                mail: true
            },
            subjct: {
                required: true,
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
            var result = {};
            $.each(postData, function () {
                result[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="contact_form" method="post">
<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="f_name" name="fname" placeholder="First Name *">
<input type="text" class="l_name" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="number" class="phone_number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number *">
<input type="email" class="mail_val" name="mail" placeholder="Email ID">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject *" name="subjct" class="subjct_content">
<textarea class="form_textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't you just add an extra class which will set display:none to error message container(label/span) where it appears?

Comment: done. I've set `display:none` to that `label`. Now doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark red to empty box you can add following to your `validate` function:

```
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
               $('form input,textarea').each(function(){
                   if($(this).val() == ""){
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red'); 
                   }
               });
            }, 

    errorPlacement: function(){
                return false;  // suppresses error message text
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
jQuery(".contact_form").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
            },
            lname: {
                required: true,
            },
            location: {
                required: true,
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            },
            mail: {
                required: true,
                mail: true
            },
            subjct: {
                required: true,
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
            var result = {};
            $.each(postData, function () {
                result[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            return false;
        },
       errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
            return true;
         }
    });
```

OR you can simply set the error label/span to following style

```
display:none
```

Comment: Label hided. But how to show red color border of input text. when it was empty while clicking submit